# How to build models according to other model's records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

For example:

Environment:

Ruby 1.9.2

Rails 3.0.5

Mongoid

I have a Survey model and embeds many Questions in it. Now I want to define a function "publish" in surveys_controller.rb which can create model dynamically according to Survey's records (i.e., objects). **For example, I have an survey object (with survey.id), the object instance has n (might be different across survey objects) questions (each with quesiton.id). Once I create a survey object, I want to build a model accordingly: name the collection with "s{@survey.id}" and create n fields named "q{@question.id}".**

```
#surveys_controller.rb
def publish
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @questions = Survey.questions
  ... how to build a model? ...
  ... and how to set collection name using "s{@survey.id}" ...
  @questions.each do |question|
    ... and then how to add fields (named with "q{question.id}") and define type (named with question.type) ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow your question. But are you looking for this?

```
@new_question = @survey.questions.build
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference

Comment: Not this one. In my environment: Survey embeds many questions, question embedded in Survey. All these work well. However, I want to build third kind models (not third model). Each third kind model corresponded to a survey and has many fields which corresponded to @survey.questions. Third kind models are responsible for record answers for each survey (each survey might have different questions set).